# How to print a properly sorted Radix Trie

Tags: algorithm, tree, trie, radix

I was trying to print a properly sorted Radix Trie but when I tried to do it, it does with DFS but single letters are printed in a wrong place... What am I doing wrong? Am I doing wrong with the recursion or do I need another condition that I'm missing?

```
Ex: 

0692
072755
0
1008
1076
10
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Trie {
    static class TrieNode {
        TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[128];
        boolean leaf;
    }

    public static void insertString(TrieNode rootNode, String s) {
        TrieNode root = rootNode;
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            TrieNode next = root.children[ch];
            if (next == null)
                root.children[ch] = next = new TrieNode();
            root = next;
        }
        root.leaf = true;
    }

    public static void printSorted(TrieNode node, String s) {
        for (char ch = 0; ch < node.children.length; ch++) {
            TrieNode child = node.children[ch];
            if (child != null)
                printSorted(child, s + ch);
        }
        if (node.leaf) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TrieNode root = new TrieNode();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in)
        );
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            insertString(root, line);
            line = null;
        }

        printSorted(root, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your printSorted function, try printing the leaf first as the leaf is always less than its children.